# why ReentrantLock signal() isn't working?

Tags: java, multithreading, async-await, signals

Although i waked the Thread by signal(), Thread still in waiting pool(i think) and it  works only once.

```
while(true){
professor.ask();
}
```

because of the code  i thought it shoud repeat ask again and again

i have two Threads "Student","Jogyo"
if Student asks then, Jogyo get signal().vice versa.

below is my code

```
public class LockEx1 {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Professor professor = new Professor();

    new Thread(new Student(professor), "student kim").start();
    new Thread(new JoGyo(professor), "assistant choi").start();

    try{Thread.sleep(20000);}catch (InterruptedException e){}
    System.exit(0);
}
}

class Student implements Runnable {
Professor professor; // shared resource

Student(Professor professor) {
    this.professor = professor;
}

@Override
public void run() {
    while (true) {
        professor.ask();
    }
}
}

class JoGyo implements Runnable {
Professor professor; // shared resource

JoGyo(Professor professor) {
    this.professor = professor;
}

@Override
public void run() {
    while (true) {
        try {Thread.sleep(100);} catch (InterruptedException e) {}//catch
        professor.ask();
    }
}
}


class Professor {
private final ReentrantLock lock = new ReentrantLock();

Condition forJoGyo = lock.newCondition();
Condition forStudent = lock.newCondition();

// 교수님께 질문하기
public void ask() {
    lock.lock(); // sync -- start
    String name = Thread.currentThread().getName();
    System.out.println(name + ": have a question. professor!");
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        try {Thread.sleep(500);} catch (InterruptedException e) {}
        System.out.println("professor: " + "explaining.." + i + " " + name + " listening.." );
    }//for
    System.out.println(name + ": thanks professor");
    if (name.contains("assistant")) {
        try{forJoGyo.await();}catch (InterruptedException e){} // 조교 재우기

        forStudent.signal(); // 학생 깨우기
    }
    else if (name.contains("student")) {
        try{forStudent.await();}catch (InterruptedException e){} // 학생 재우기

        forJoGyo.signal(); // 조교 깨우기
    }
    lock.unlock(); // sync -- end
}//ask
}
```

[image]

as you see..it works(ask to professor each only onces at all) only once. is this because signal() is not working? why it doesn't repeat asking to  professor..

Answer (score 0):

The code does not execute any further because it is in a [deadlock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deadlock) state.

1. Student executes the `ask` method on the Professor object. The printing code is executed and the lock condition `forStudent` is starting to block (`await`) the thread until a signal.
2. Assistant executes the `ask` method on the Professor object. The printing code is executed an the lock condition `foJoGyo` is starting to block (`await`) the thread until an await signal.

Both threads are now waiting for a signal from the other one. None can reach the signal code, so the threads are locked forever (deadlock) - in this case until the sleep time before returning from the `main` method is reached.

The signal unlocking the other thread should be emitted before starting the waiting for the signal from the other thread, otherwise both threads will wait forever.

```java
if (name.contains("assistant")) {
    forStudent.signal();
    try {
        forJoGyo.await();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
} else if (name.contains("student")) {
    forJoGyo.signal();
    try {
        forStudent.await();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Result:

```
student kim: have a question. professor!
professor: explaining..0 student kim listening..
professor: explaining..1 student kim listening..
professor: explaining..2 student kim listening..
professor: explaining..3 student kim listening..
professor: explaining..4 student kim listening..
student kim: thanks professor
assistant choi: have a question. professor!
professor: explaining..0 assistant choi listening..
professor: explaining..1 assistant choi listening..
professor: explaining..2 assistant choi listening..
professor: explaining..3 assistant choi listening..
professor: explaining..4 assistant choi listening..
assistant choi: thanks professor
student kim: have a question. professor!
professor: explaining..0 student kim listening..
professor: explaining..1 student kim listening..
professor: explaining..2 student kim listening..
professor: explaining..3 student kim listening..
professor: explaining..4 student kim listening..
student kim: thanks professor
assistant choi: have a question. professor!
professor: explaining..0 assistant choi listening..
professor: explaining..1 assistant choi listening..
professor: explaining..2 assistant choi listening..
professor: explaining..3 assistant choi listening..
professor: explaining..4 assistant choi listening..
assistant choi: thanks professor
student kim: have a question. professor!
professor: explaining..0 student kim listening..
professor: explaining..1 student kim listening..
professor: explaining..2 student kim listening..
professor: explaining..3 student kim listening..
professor: explaining..4 student kim listening..
student kim: thanks professor
assistant choi: have a question. professor!
professor: explaining..0 assistant choi listening..
professor: explaining..1 assistant choi listening..
professor: explaining..2 assistant choi listening..
professor: explaining..3 assistant choi listening..
professor: explaining..4 assistant choi listening..
assistant choi: thanks professor
student kim: have a question. professor!
professor: explaining..0 student kim listening..
professor: explaining..1 student kim listening..
professor: explaining..2 student kim listening..
professor: explaining..3 student kim listening..
professor: explaining..4 student kim listening..
student kim: thanks professor
```

**Important sidenote: `unlock` call should be placed inside a `finally` block with `try` block containing the code after `lock` to avoid a situation when the lock is never unlocked in case of an exception or an early return**.